# How to compile C++ app for Windows XP in MSVS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-xp, compatibility

As I read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp?view=msvc-170), it is enough to download most recent [MSVS 2022](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/free-developer-offers/) and then install toolset `C++ Windows XP Support for VS 2017 (v141) tools [Deprecated]`.

After that in Visual Studio inside project properties I set this toolset. According to linked article it is enough to compile C++ app with XP support.

But after my `.exe` file is created if I run it on XP 64-bit SP2 then it shows error that `CompareStringEx` function is not found in `KERNEL32.DLL`.

Hence it appears that it is not enough to use this toolset. Something else is needed.

In some other places I see that one needs also to add define `/D_USING_V110_SDK71_` when compiling and option `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.01` when linking. In my project properties I also tried to add this two options, but still `CompareStringEx` is inside import table of final application.

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70263892/how-to-compile-c-app-for-windows-xp-in-msvs#comment124207382_70263892) by @BenVoigt, I did defines `/DWINVER=0x0502 /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0502`.  Also set C++ standard to `/std:c++14` (I would set C++11 but this MSVS version allows to set only C++14 at minimum). Still some non-XP symbols remain in final EXE like [InitializeSRWLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializesrwlock) that is possibly used by C++11's [std::mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) in my code.

Does anyone know everything what is needed in order to compile fully XP-compatible application?

**Update**. I managed to build working XP application by doing things above plus setting C++ CRT runtime to `Multi Threaded DLL`, i.e. using dynamic DLL linkage of CRT. Also as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70263892/how-to-compile-c-app-for-windows-xp-in-msvs?noredirect=1#comment124245242_70263892) by @ChuckWalbourn (down [x86](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/VC_redist.x86.exe) or [x64](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/VC_redist.x64.exe) redists), I downloaded older version of `msvcp140.dll`.

But it is very important for my project to have statically linked runtime (C++ CRT), i.e. use `Multi Threaded` value for Runtime field in project properties. Only if it is REALLY not possible only then I will use DLL CRT. Until then solution about how to link CRT statically are welcome, of course to produce XP-compatible EXE.

Comment: Have you set `WINVER` as described in [Using the Windows Headers -- Setting WINVER or _WIN32_WINNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers#setting-winver-or-_win32_winnt) ?

Comment: @BenVoigt Can you suggest what `WINVER` should be set to support XP 64-bit SP2? Is it `0x0502`?

Comment: Yes, the table on that same page indicated `0x0502` for XP Service Pack 2 (or later)

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, after your change `CompareStringEx` disappeared from all `.obj` files of my project. But still final `.exe` has this symbol imported. It means some `.lib` file is linked into final exe that uses this symbol. I suspect that it is `hid.lib`, although `hid.dll` is present Win XP system folder, still I can't find any `hid.lib` in Windows SDK 7 (last SDK that supports XP). Do you possibly know any place where I can download `hid.lib` compiled for XP? I need it in my code.

Comment: @BenVoigt Removing `hid.lib` from linking and commenting out usage of functions of this library didn't help. Final `.exe` still has `CompareStringEx` import symbol.

Comment: And your toolchain is set to `v141_xp` ?  In seeming contradiction to the name which appears in the installer, that toolpack does not add Windows XP Support to the `v141` toolchain, it installs a separate `v141_xp` toolchain

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, tooset name is called `v141_xp` and it is set in my project properties in `Toolset` field. More and more I start to think that some linked in libraries are providing these non-XP symbols. Because if I compile my project with non-v141_xp toolset then all `.obj` files of my project contain non-XP symbols. Then if I use `v141_xp` then all of my `.obj` files have NO non-XP symbols at all. But still final .exe has these symbols. So it looks like only at linker stage they appear and they are coming not from my .obj file, but from external libraries.

Comment: @BenVoigt I myself don't link any WinApi libraries in project properties, although I use some (not many) WinApi functions. Probably these used functions are covered by default set of linked in libraries, default set of any MSVC project. Also I use a lot of STD C++ library functions and classes. So this STD C++ library can pull non-XP dependencies. Maybe from C++20 or C++17 STD library can't be used in XP and you have to set option like `/std:c++14` or `/std:c++11` at compile time, do you know? For example one non-XP symbol `InitializeSRWLock` can happen due to me using `std::mutex`.

Comment: The toolchain option should control where compiler-provided libraries such as the C++ Standard Library are fetched.... the .lib files for `v141_xp` shouldn't have any usage of e.g. `InitializeSRWLock`, whether that means a different implementation or that some classes are simply missing.  Are you using an third-party static libraries?

Comment: And while the new project wizard does put some import libraries (for WinAPI DLLs) in by default, you can edit that list in project properties.  Be careful also of `#pragma comment(lib)` which can tell the linker to link certain libraries, bypassing project settings.  The linker itself should only be adding the C Standard Library and C++ Standard Library and not defaulting you into any WinAPI import libraries.

Comment: @BenVoigt No other libraries besides std C++ library is not used. Few WinApi functions are used also but they all are present in XP. So I'm guessing that STD C++ library implements some of classes in XP-incomptatible way.

Comment: @BenVoigt I guess MSVS adds some WinApi libs on linking stage because I use WinApi functions from several Win DLLs and don't put any `.lib` files in Additional Libraries field. So I guess MSVS tries to link some very standard libraries like Kernel32.lib/User32.lib/Advapi32.lib, etc.

Comment: In my experience (every version of Visual C++ up through Visual Studio 2017) libraries such as `user32.lib`, and `advapi32.lib` were linked only if they were listed in the Linker->Input page of project properties, or found in `#pragma comment(lib)`.  The new project wizard would put them into the Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies list but you were free to take them out and the linker respected that.  `kernel32.dll` is loaded into every process whether you import anything from it or not of course, but you are seeing explicit imports (I assume from `dumpbin /imports`)

Comment: If you look at Linker->Command Line in the project properties, do you see the libraries you are trying to track down?  If they are added by property pages or indirectly through a variable, they will show up there.

Comment: Also, have you checked whether using the same toolchain, `WINVER`, and linker options on a simple "Hello World" application still generates the XP-incompatible imports?

Comment: Actually, have you verified that the import is in your executable, and not in the VC++ DLLs loaded by your executable?  Also are you aware of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/325993/vc-redist-1418-breaks-windows-xp-compatibility.html ?

Comment: You may also want to read https://building.enlyze.com/posts/modern-visual-studio-meets-ancient-windows/ and https://building.enlyze.com/posts/targeting-25-years-of-windows-with-visual-studio-2019/

Comment: @BenVoigt Additional Dependencies contains only `my_lib.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)`, where I added just `my_lib.lib`, that is my library that contains only std C++ library usage and few XP-compatible winapi calls. `%(AdditionalDependencies)` was default value of this field when I created project. `Command Line` field value of linker contains [this text](https://cutt.ly/UYQjxh0), as you can see it has quite a lot of winapi libs added, but all they were added not by me. Also this field contains only single library from my (non winapi) side `my_lib.lib`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Probably I know the reason - in my project I statically linked C++ runtime by specifying `Runtime Library` field equal to `Multi-threaded`. But just for a check I modified it to be dynamically linked `Multi-threaded DLL`, and it appeared that final EXE contained `msvcp140.dll` in import table. But if you look into `msvcp140.dll` then you can see that is `InitializeSRWLock` and `CompareStringEx` in its import table, both of these functions are not present in XP. So for some reason `v141_xp` toolset linked this `msvcp140.dll` library. How do I force older DLL to use?

Comment: You are looking at the wrong version of ``msvcp140.dll``. You are looking at the 14.2x version. You need to be using the 14.16 version or older. You have to deploy the [x64](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/VC_redist.x64.exe) or [x86](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/VC_redist.x86.exe) version on Windows XP. While the latest REDIST is binary compatible with older VCs, the v142 and v143 version of the CRT REDIST doesn't support Window XP.

Comment: The CRT requirement is in fact detailed in that article. The VS 2019 (16.7) REDIST was the last one that supports Windows XP. Since you are using the ``v141_xp`` toolset, you should use the V141 VC++ REDIST anyhow.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Thanks for joining conversation! If you read post of my Question then you can see that I installed `v141_xp` toolset of MSVS. And this toolset automatically links to some library. I guess it should correctly link to what is necessary to support XP, otherwise why this toolset is called `v141_xp`. If I link static runtime then I see these non-XP symbols in final EXE, same symbols as found in my `c:\windows\system32\msvcp140.dll`. As I understand you're saying that there exists some other version of `msvcp140.dll`,can you point me to the Download Link of this older library version?

Comment: ``MSVCP140.DLL`` exists in all versions of the Visual C++ REDIST from VS 2015 Update 3 through VS 2022. Per [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017) you can run a program C++ built with VS 2015 Update 3 or VS 2017 or VS 2019 with the latest VC++ 2022 REDIST installed. So if you built your program with ``v141_xp`` then it will run just fine on a Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8.x, Windows 10/11 system with any VC++ REDIST since the VS 2017 release.

Comment: @Arty: That's what I said, that the project wizard adds a bunch of windows libraries to the link command line by default (recently that is via the `%(AdditionalDependencies)` variable, formerly it actually listed each one) but you are free to remove them if you choose.

Comment: @BenVoigt So current status update is that successfully built XP-compatible version of my project only by setting `Multi Threaded DLL` runtime library, in other words did dynamic (DLL) linkage of C++ CRT and also downloaded older version of `msvcp140.dll` as suggested by Chuck Walbourn (comments above). This application runs on XP. But the problem is that it is very important for my project to link C++ CRT statically i.e. use `Multi Threaded` runtime (non-DLL version). Only if it is totally impossible to do static CRT link only then I'll use dynamic runtime. So suggestions are welcome!

Comment: @Arty: You'll need to get the static library version of the older VCRedist version.  The (rather large) problem is then your executable will use that version on all operating systems, and miss the fixes present in newer VCRedist versions designed for Vista+.  (And even if you link two versions, one for XP one for Vista+, you still will be locked to that version regardless of any Windows Updates the user installs)  That's why it is recommended to link to the VCRedist dynamically.

Comment: @BenVoigt Do you have any idea where I can get (download) statical version of `msvcp140.dll`?

Comment: @BenVoigt Dynamic version I downloaded [from here](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/VC_redist.x86.exe), but where to get exactly this version but statical? And also second question - what about std C++ library header files? Do I need to get also headers for that version? Or headers are exactly the same through all versions of this library?

Comment: @BenVoigt If you're interested, my task was solved. To make static linked app XP-compatible I had to download packages [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70263892/how-to-compile-c-app-for-windows-xp-in-msvs/70285486#comment124262480_70285486). After they were downloaded all non-XP symbols disappeared from EXE. No other setup of packages was needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** For Window XP VC++ REDIST support, install  https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/VC_redist.x86.exe on your Windows XP system

-or-

if you are doing "side-by-side application local deployment", then use the DLLs from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\<edition>\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.16.27012\x86\Microsoft.VC141.CRT`.

> If you want the latest bug fixes to the CRT, you can also download the REDIST for VS 2019 (16.7) per the link on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp?view=msvc-170).

For Windows XP targeting, you use the `v141_xp` Platform Toolset installed by Visual Studio (VS 2017, VS 2019, or VS 2022) which is the latest VS 2017 (`v141`) C++ compiler using an included Windows 7.1A SDK.

Make sure you have installed (for VS 2022) the following individual components since you are using MFC:

- `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WinXP`: *C++ Windows XP Support for VS 2017 (v141) tools [Deprecated]*
- `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v141.x86.x64`: *MSVC v141 - VS 2017 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.16)*
- `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v141.MFC`: *C++ MFC for v141 build tools (x86 & x64)*

> If you are doing DirectX development, be sure to read [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/visual-studio-2012-update-1/) as well for various implications of using the Windows 7.1A SDK.

For deployment to Windows XP, you can install the latest VS 2017 Visual C++ REDIST or use VS 2019 Visual C++ up to VS 2019 (16.7). After that the REDIST DLLs themselves are *not compatible with Windows XP*.

On your development system with VS 2022 installed, you are going to have a newer set of Visual C++ REDIST files which are [binary compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017) with your `v141_xp` Platform Toolset built EXE, but those VC++ REDIST DLLs *are not* compatible with Windows XP.

> IOW: If you look at a `dumpbin /imports` of the 14.30 (v143 version), 14.29 (v142 latest version), and/or 14.16 (v141 latest version ) copies of `msvcp140.dll` you will see different imports. The `msvcp140.dll` sitting in your `C:\windows\SysWOW64` folder is going to be the 14.30 version.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Indeed after I linked CRT dynamically and used your links to download/install older version of `msvcp140.dll` then my application run on XP successfully. But after installing `C++ Windows XP Support for VS 2017 (v141) tools [Deprecated]` toolset oldest Redist I have is `D:\bin2\VisualStudio\2022\Preview\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.29.30133\x86\Microsoft.VC142.MFC`, which is also not CRT but MFC. I don't have folder `14.16` or anything similar. Do I have to look into other locations on my disk, or maybe install some other package in MSVS installer?

Comment: Also for my project is very important to have statically linked CRT, not as a separate `msvcp140.dll`, is it possible to achieve same working XP-compatible version with statical CRT link? How do I do that? I need EXE application without any external deployed DLLs if possible, except for defaultly installed XP dlls. If not possible of course I'll deploy old `msvc140.dll` redist that you linked.

Comment: Make sure you have installed the individual components "MSVC v141 - VS 2017 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.16)", "C++ Windows XP Support for VS 2017 (v141) tools [Deprecated]", and "C++ MFC for v141 build tools (x86 & x64)". That should give you the needed DLLs/libs.

Comment: You described how to compile in such a way that dynamic `msvcp140.dll` is used. And such compiled app successfully runs on XP. Do you know how can I build app in such a way that same version of runtime is linked statically? Statical link happens when I set `Runtime` to `Multi Threaded`. But if link statically then I get XP-incompatible version, while if I use dynamic `Multi Threaded DLL` then everything works. Can you suggest how to achieve working app with static Runtime link? Didn't do installs from previous your comment yet, will it help in static link?

Comment: Start by adding the missing components and then retry.

Comment: Thanks, looks great! At least right now those non-compatible functions disappeared in static build. After installing those 3 packages that you mentioned [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70263892/how-to-compile-c-app-for-windows-xp-in-msvs/70285486?noredirect=1#comment124262480_70285486). Still I tested this only on one laptop, but XP is installed on another one (in virtual machine), few hours later I'll try to run this EXE on that XP. And reply to you. Would be great if you add these 3 packages to your Answer, as it solved my issue, and I'll accept your answer!

Comment: Thanks, accepted! Would be great also that you include [x64](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/VC_redist.x64.exe) redist download link near `x86` link that you already have. Because for me `x64` is valueable to as I often use `64-bit Edition` of XP. So both links are good for solving my task, 32/64.

Comment: Windows XP x64 (which is basically Windows Server 2003 SP1). That's one from the "wayback" machine :)